# How to clip part of a text in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a text that's drawn on a HTML5 canvas. How do I clip or hide part of the text that is to the left of a line?

In this example, the part of the word 'HELLO' is clipped to the left of the red line.

There are two restrictions:

1. Everything is to be drawn on the same canvas. No new canvases to be created
2. The red line in my real work is the y-axis of a chart. To the left side of the red line are the labels for the axis. So imagine there are stuff drawn on that side and they need to show. That part can't be blocked or erased.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to Jarrod’s useful technique is using a clipping region when drawing your text.

For example if your y-axis is at 30px, this clip will not draw text to the left of 30px

```
ctx.rect(30,0,canvas.width-30,canvas.height);
ctx.clip();
```

Then `fillText` will leave anything left of your y-axis undisturbed (resulting in your “-ELLO”)

```
ctx.fillText(theText,20,50);
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Q5Pfa/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    clipTextToGrid(50,"HELLO","48px verdana");

    function clipTextToGrid(leftAxisBorder,theText,font){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(leftAxisBorder,0,canvas.width-leftAxisBorder,canvas.height);
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.font=font;
        ctx.fillText(theText,3,50);
        ctx.restore();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could draw your text to an off screen canvas (that being a new canvas that is in memory), then draw that canvas to your main canvas, applying your clipping.

This will allow you to draw any part of your offscreen canvas, such as "clipping" it to get the effect you're after. This can be done with regular `drawImage` method:

```
 ctx.drawImage([x: adjust for clipping], y, w, h, sourceCanvas, 0, 0, w, h);
```

You'll of course have to cacluate how much to clip.

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

<strike>1) If you want to clip the **end** of the text, you can use the optional `maxWidth` parameter of [fillText()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp).</strike>

2) Other clipping method using `globalCompositeOperation` is represented [here](http://jsbin.com/jegaz/2/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found is to use `globalCompositeOperation`:

(In the example below I set the background to light green to show the transparency after clipping)

```js
// SETUP 

ctx = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
ctx.rect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.font = `20px sans-serif`;
ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
ctx.fillText("HELLO", 10, 30)

// CLIPPING CODE

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(65, 10, 20, 25);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas width="100" height="50" style="background: lightgreen" />
```